# What causes the nose landing gear knocking noise on a Boeing 777 while taxiing?

Tags: taxiing, noise

The NLG knocking noise heard on taxi-in to stand, what could cause this knocking noise?

Answer (score 4):

[image]
([source](http://airportfocusinternational.com/atg-airports-unveils-cross-airfield-range-of-products/))

That's a pilot taxiing perfectly on the centerline, which makes one of the two nose landing gear tires hit all the [taxiway centerline lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxiway#Lights).

Just like the sound the tires of a car make when they hit the [cat's eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_eye_(road)) on a road at speed.

Comment: Based on the configuration of the 777's [nose gear](https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3239/3107272207_9bceae5823_z.jpg) (image), I'd say the pilot was a bit off-center.